# Lumen + nginx = error 500, rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php"

Tags: redirect, laravel, nginx, php, lumen

I'm trying to setup [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/introduction) - "micro-framework" built on top of Laravel's components. On server-side there's nginx + php-fpm.

Here's my nginx config:

```nginx
server {
    server_name lumen.dev;
    root /var/www/lumen;

    location / {
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME      /index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/lumen/public/index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

This config work fine when I'm calling defined route, e.g. I see "Lumen." response when opening http://lumen.dev. But when I try to open undefined route like http://lumen.dev/404 I see "500 Internal Server Error" in browser and this message in nginx error log:

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: lumen.dev

How can I fix my nginx conf to make it working?

Comment: Yay first Lumen question! :) I'm pretty sure you need to set `root` to `/var/www/lumen/public`

Comment: @lukasgeiter damn, how can I miss that? :) Please separate your comment to answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `root` option has to point to the public directory:

```
server {
    server_name lumen.dev;
    root /var/www/lumen/public;
```

The error appears because it's trying to call `/index.php?$query_string` which is relative to the root. So it tries to find `/var/www/lumen/index.php` in an endless loop.

Comment: HI. And how to do the same thing on a web server online ? Using a .htaccess in the root directory ?

Comment: @zlen That depends on the server and your hoster. For apache you'd use a virtual host config